# Problems with change the active list when scrolling navbar

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change active when scrolling in nav bar but it's doesn't work with my code

Here, this is my js code

```js
<script>
let navbar = document.getElementById("nav ul li");
    let viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    let navHeight = document.getElementById("nav ul li").offsetHeight;

    let navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
        scrollpos = window.scrollY;
        navbarLinks.forEach(link => {
            let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);
            if (section.offsetTop <= scrollpos + 20 &&
                section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > scrollpos + 20) {
                link.classList.add("active");
            } else {
                link.classList.remove("active");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here, this is my html code

```html
<nav>
        <div class="header">Profile</div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#page1" class="active">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Social</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">MyWorks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page6">Encouragement</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page7">Technique</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: First two `getElementbyId` should be `querySelector` I think

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to create navbar active when scrolling like this web >>> https://dev.to/areeburrub/change-nav-link-s-style-as-you-scroll-4p62

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I think you should use `document.querySelectorAll(...)` instead of `document.getElementById(...)`, (line 2 & 4)

because you are using a CSS QUERY SELECTOR. you should use `getElementById` only when you are selecting an element by it's `id`.

Comment: I try document.querySelectorAll(...) instead of getElementById but When I scroll to page3 or click on navbar page3 its don't get any class active

Comment: Can you send us a demo from your code? you can use CodePen Project.